# Query to include non-protected resources only

Tags: c#, asp.net, linq, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

I am using Entity Framework to retrieve data from my database. You can see the database model here:

[image: edmx]

I'm attempting to build a repeater where I show Resource Categories only if there is a resource `where IsProtected == false`.  Then an nested repeater showing the Resource itself.

Here is an abbreviated repeater to help clarify what I'm looking for

```
<asp:Repeater>
    <h2>Category Name</h2>
    <ol>
        <asp:Repeater DataSource="<%# ((ResourceCategory)Container.DataItem).Resource %>">
            <li>Resource Name</li>
        </asp:Repeater>
    </ol>
</asp:Repeater>
```

The query that I'm currently uses does pull up any category that has a `Resource.Count() > 0`, but not sure how to write my `where` statement since it is actually related to the `Resource` table:

```
public List<Model.ResourceCategory> GetResourcesWithDocuments()
{
    using (var context = new SafetyInSightEntities())
    {
        return (from cat in context.ResourceCategory.Include("Resource")
                orderby cat.Name
                where cat.Resource.Count > 0
                select cat).ToList();
    }
}
```

Can someone please help me rewrite my LINQ query so my inner repeater only shows resources where `IsProtected == false`

Comment: If you add `using System.Data.Entity;` then you can use a neat extension method: `context.ResourceCategory.Include(cat => cat.Resources)`

Comment: How is that different than the include I used? (not being sarcastic, just learning)

Comment: Then you're not limited by inlined string constant but table name to include will be determined for you, and will survive over refactoring, etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not exactly sure what you are asking, but I would assume you want this?

```
public List<Model.ResourceCategory> GetResourcesWithDocuments()
{
    using (var context = new SafetyInSightEntities())
    {
        return (from cat in context.ResourceCategory
                orderby cat.Name
                where cat.Resource.Any()
                select new 
                {
                    CategoryName = cat.Name,
                    Resources = cat.Resource.Where(r => r.IsProtected == false).ToList()
                }).ToList();
    }
}
```

It's possible you want to use `All` rather than `Any`, but not sure based on the question.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear.  I need the category names, and then inner repeater will show each resource within the category where IsProtected == false. I'll edit the question to show the nested repeater that should help

Comment: Not sure if entity framework supports nested collection or not, but that would be what you would need I believe

Comment: Error I'm getting: Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.List<AnonymousType#1>' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List<SafetyInSight.DataAccess.Model.ResourceCategory>'

Comment: Don't cast as resource, just databind directly, otherwise you will need to do a lot more work that what is here. Bind to CategoryName for the category name, and Resources for the child repeater.

Comment: Problem that you has return type Category but actually returns an anonymous type.

Comment: Yeah, just use Bind("CategoryName") and Bind("Resources")

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
public IEnumerable<ResourceCategoryFacade> GetResourcesWithDocuments() // return weaker interface
{
    using (var context = new SafetyInSightEntities())
    {
        var q = from cat in context.ResourceCategory.Include(cat => cat.Resource)
                orderby cat.Name
                select new ResourceCategoryFacade // anonymous, or compiler-time type
                {
                    CategoryName = cat.Name,
                    Resources = cat.Resource.Where(r => !r.IsProtected).ToList() // or ToArray()
                };
        return q.ToList(); // or ToArray()
    }
}
```

Comment: I edited the question to show you the nested repeater.  I need the category name and then a list of resources where IsProtected == false

Comment: @JonHarding: Okay, so what the problem returning Category itself, then access its Name and Resource properties? I mean difficulty in LINQ or markup?

Comment: @JonHarding: Seems I understood, from your description and Darren's code.

Comment: hate to be picky, there seem to be some syntax errors. it doesn't recognize the 'q' on the return